# Pleas help me float this navbar to the left

Tags: image, navbar

Long story short..I need my navbar to float on top of an image background (don't want to make the image into a background image). I have managed to place the navbar on the image but its in the left corner. I need it in the right corner! Please help.

http://vetamera.nu/DK/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add `right: 0;` to your `.top-nav` class.

```
.top-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    width: 750px;
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked but when the screen size is minimized its placed in the center. whys that?

Comment: @SarahA I see you have `left: -30px;` in the css? can you remove `float: right;
    left: -30px;` and keep `right: 10px;`